# "In der Schlacht um Tirad Pass" or "bei Tirad Pass"?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german, preposition

How do you say "The Battle of Tirad Pass" in German?

> Gregorio del Pilar wurde im Jahre 1899 in der Schlacht bei Tirad Pass umgebracht.
>
> Gregorio del Pilar wurde im Jahre 1899 in der Schlacht um Tirad Pass umgebracht.

This is the English sentence:

> Gregorio del Pilar was killed in 1899 in the Battle of Tirad-Pass.

Comment: By the way, "dying as a soldier during the normal events of battle" is "fallen" *(Er fiel in der Schlacht am Tirad-Pass).* "Er wurde umgebracht" would indicate that he was a victim of a (war) crime.

Comment: Oder, euphemistisch: "Er ist am Tirad Pass geblieben."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die beiden Formulierungen haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

**die Schlacht um [Objekt]**

Hier ist [Objekt] das Objekt, um das gekämpft wird. Wer die Schlacht gewinnt, wird Eigentümer dieses Objekts. Das kann ein Gebäude, ein Landstrich oder sogar ein ganzer Staat sein. Auch eine Schlacht *um* ein bestimmtes Recht (z.B. Erbfolge) ist denkbar.

**die Schlacht am/bei/auf [Ort]**

Hier wird angegeben, wo die Schlacht stattfand. Das kann eine Siedlung, ein Landstrich, eine bestimmte Bucht oder jeder beliebige andere geographische Ort sein.

Nur wenn bei einer Schlacht um genau jenes Gebiet gekämpft wird an dem die Schlacht stattfindet (was sehr häufig der Fall ist) sind beide Formulierungen erlaubt. Aber auch hier gilt, dass sie nicht dasselbe bedeuten.

---

Im konkreten Fall würde ich die folgende Formulierung vorziehen:

> Gregorio del Pilar wurde im Jahre 1899 in der Schlacht **am** Tirad-Pass getötet.

Besser noch:

> Gregorio del Pilar fiel im Jahre 1899 in der Schlacht **am** Tirad-Pass.

Ergänzungen dazu:

- »umbringen« ist ein Synonym von »ermorden«; bei Schlachten wird man nicht ermordet sondern getötet. Bei einem Mord wird gezielt und vorsätzlich eine ganz bestimmte Person ums Leben gebracht. Wenn vorher nicht ausdrücklich geplant war, diese spezielle Person zu töten war es kein Mord sondern eben nur eine Tötung. Tritt der Tod als unmittelbare Folge einer kriegerischen Auseinandersetzung ein, ist »fallen« das Verb der ersten Wahl. In diesem Fall ist es aber nicht mehr möglich den Satz im Passiv zu formulieren weil »fallen« ein intransitives Verb ist. (korrekt: »Ich ermorde dich« und »Ich töte dich«. Falsch: »Ich fälle dich«. Stattdessen richtig: »Du fällst«)
- »Tirad-Pass« ist im Deutschen ein Wort (nicht zwei Wörter) und muss daher mit Bindestrich (also »Tirad-Pass«) oder zusammen (»Tiradpass«) geschrieben werden, so wie hier: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirad-Pass-Nationalpark

Falls es bei dieser Schlacht tatsächlich nur um die Eroberung dieses Gebirgspasses ging, könnte man auch sagen:

> Gregorio del Pilar wurde im Jahre 1899 in der Schlacht **um den** Tirad-Pass getötet.

Den Artikel »den« darf man in diesem Fall nicht weglassen, weil »Pass« kein Eigenname ist (obwohl es in diesem Fall Bestandteil eines Eigennamens ist). Das Thema »Artikel von geographischen Begriffen« ist aber ein separates Thema, das hier zu weit führen würde.

Comment: Für die Unterscheidung zwischen "umgebracht/ermordet werden" und "sterben/fallen" kommt es weniger darauf an, ob eine *bestimmte* Person getötet wird, sondern ob es sich um einen "fairen Kampf" gehandelt hat. Wenn ein Selbstmordattentäter auf dem Marktplatz eine Bombe zündet oder ein Offizier *nach* einer Schlacht wehrlose Gefangene erschießen läßt, dann ist "wurde umgebracht/ermordet" richtig, obwohl die Opfer *unbestimmte Personen* sind. Umgekehrt würde man bei jemandem, der in einem Duell stirbt, eher nicht "wurde umgebracht" sagen, obwohl das Opfer hier eine bestimmte Person ist.

Comment: @Uwe: Das Ausschlaggebende beim Morden ist tatsächlich nicht, dass es sich um eine bestimmte, vorher gezielt ausgewählte Person handelt, sondern dass vorher die Absicht bestand jemanden zu töten. Insofern gebe ich dir recht, dass der Selbstmordattentäter und der Offizier in deinem Beispiel Mörder sind. Im Falle des Duells liegt eine ähnliche Situation wie bei einer Schlacht vor: Derjenige, der dabei stirbt wusste vorher, dass er bei diesem Vorgang mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit sterben würde. Ich denke, da könnte man sehr lange darüber streiten ob das dann ein Mord ist.

Comment: +1 exzellenter Beitrag, wiewohl ich @Uwe bzgl. der juristischen Frage Recht geben würde. Schließlich zieht man ja auch in eine Schlacht mit dem Vorsatz, zu töten (was sonst?), dennoch sind Gefallene eben keine Ermordeten.

Answer (score 3):

Beim Pass (oder am Pass; wenn der Ort ein Pass, Fluss oder Berg ist, kann man "am" verwenden, aber nicht bei Städten), wenn die Schlacht da stattfand; um, wenn man sich wirklich um diesen Pass geprügelt hat.

Comment: Was ist, wenn der Schlacht im Meer stattfand, wie z.B. The Battle of Manila Bay? Hier ist mein Versuch :  Der Schlacht an der Bucht von Manila?

Comment: In der Bucht (oder im Golf von xyz), wenn es eben wirklich da passiert; auf dem Bodensee, auf dem Rhein, am Strand der Normandie. An der Bucht klingt für mich nach "am Strand am Rande der Bucht".